# SQL Query subselect optimization in WHERE clause (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, subquery, query-optimization

I write the following SELECT statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT someColumn1
FROM someTable
WHERE someColumn2 = (SELECT MAX(someColumn2) FROM someTable)
    AND someColumn3 IN ('Value1','Value2','Value3','Value4','Value5')
ORDER BY someColumn1
```

The table contains about 1 000 000 record. The WHERE clause reduces this number to 50 000. (The someColumn2 is indexed)

If I replace the subselect in the WHERE clause to a concrete value, then the query executes more faster.

That subselect executes more than one time? How can I achieve in queries like this to execute a subquery only one time?

Comment: Please post the execution plan. [Could be similar to this question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/57334/3690).

Comment: @MartinSmith Yes, it was what I searching for

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're talking abour the `(SELECT MAX` subquery (but it's not very clear from your question).

The reason it will be faster hard-coding a value instead of running the subquery is that the subquery has to read at least some of the database to get the max value, and this will be slower than just telling it 42, or whatever the value is. Looking at your query, an index on `(someColumn2, some someColumn3)` would be good: col2 to help it get the max, and once it's got it it can keep going through the Col3 values to find the ones you want, probably on the same index page, rather than having to do to the data page for each of the Col2 matches: that'll save a bit of disk IO.

Answer (score 0):

Your query as it stands is completely possible to return zero records... Why, you have no where criteria on the inner to match the outer too.  Let me clarify.  Your inner query is looking for max( somecolumn2 ), and lets say your maximum value of someColumn2 = 123.  However, your primary criteria is only for those records where someColumn3 is one of values 1-5.  If this is the case, it may be that of the 1-5 values, the highest someColumn2 might be 87 and thus never find the matching 123, let-alone getting a column 1 value.

So, to better qualify, move your someColumn3 into the inner query too and make sure you have your covering index on ( someColumn3, someColumn2, someColumn1 )

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
      someColumn1
   FROM 
      someTable
        JOIN ( SELECT MAX(someColumn2) JustOne
                 FROM someTable
                WHERE someColumn3 IN ('Value1','Value2','Value3','Value4','Value5')) QualRecs
         on someTable.someColumn2 = QualRecs.JustOne
   WHERE 
      someColumn3 IN ('Value1','Value2','Value3','Value4','Value5')
   ORDER BY 
      someColumn1
```

COMMENT FEEDBACK...

Let me clarify the issue with your original query.  Lets say you have the following data.

```
someColumn1  someColumn2   someColumn3
1            1             value1
2            5             value2
3            8             value3
4            12            value5
5            28            value7
6            48            value8
```

Now, your original query was getting the max of column 2... in this data scenario, the max value is 48, but is associated with "value8" in someColumn3.

Now, the rest of your query.  You only want distinct IDs where someColumn2 is equal to that 48 value, BUT ALSO must be of a "Value 1-5"..  In this case, no records are returned as the 48 is associated with value8 and outside your other condition.

So my query says...  The final query is based on values 1-5, so get the max value from that thus returning the #12, then it will have a match to be returned to get your distinct someColumn1 value.

Comment: But I need just those records where someColumn2 = max(someColumn2) for the entire table, so my query do what I want and this query not exactly (although it would give the same result in most of the cases)

Comment: @jannagy02, see revision and why your approach may fail... However, with your ambiguous sample query and no tangible data to understand, not completely clear, but the scenario holds true.

Comment: Yes, I understood what you wrote at the first time. But in the case you described, this query has to return with no records. And my orginal question is not about the correctness of the result, I do not wrote what I wanted to query, my question was that how I can achieve in queries like this to execute a subquery only one time.

Comment: but if I cut off the where clause from the right side of the join, I think it is the same as my original result and it executes only one time.

Comment: @jannagy02, then as I have here, use a separate query on same criteria you are considering and group by so it is done once based on whatever result key to join back to.  This way it is done once as you want and not once for every instance being processed which is VERY costly in a query.